# QuarkusIntegrationTest does not allow two tests running sequentially: application closed in 2nd test by Camel SimpleMainShutdownStrategy

Tags: apache-camel, quarkus

I have a strange error: I can only run one Quarkus integration test in my `mvn verify` step. When I have two integration tests, the second one runs but immediately stops the application so nothing is happening and building hangs forever.

The logs are different in two tests. For the 1st one, the logs are:

```
2023-01-04 15:43:04,560 INFO  [org.apa.cam.imp.eng.AbstractCamelContext] (main) Routes startup (total:8 started:8)
2023-01-04 15:43:04,560 INFO  [org.apa.cam.imp.eng.AbstractCamelContext] (main)     Started route1 (activemq://queue:myqueue)
2023-01-04 15:43:04,560 INFO  [org.apa.cam.imp.eng.AbstractCamelContext] (main)     Started route2 (activemq://queue:myqueue.online)
2023-01-04 15:43:04,560 INFO  [org.apa.cam.imp.eng.AbstractCamelContext] (main)     Started main (direct://main)
2023-01-04 15:43:04,560 INFO  [org.apa.cam.imp.eng.AbstractCamelContext] (main)     Started individual-endpoint (direct://individual-endpoint)
2023-01-04 15:43:04,560 INFO  [org.apa.cam.imp.eng.AbstractCamelContext] (main)     Started send-and-retry (direct://send-and-retry)
2023-01-04 15:43:04,560 INFO  [org.apa.cam.imp.eng.AbstractCamelContext] (main)     Started mapping-response (direct://mapping-response)
2023-01-04 15:43:04,560 INFO  [org.apa.cam.imp.eng.AbstractCamelContext] (main)     Started reply-queue (direct://reply-queue)
2023-01-04 15:43:04,560 INFO  [org.apa.cam.imp.eng.AbstractCamelContext] (main)     Started route3 (direct://receive.ack.response)
2023-01-04 15:43:04,561 INFO  [org.apa.cam.imp.eng.AbstractCamelContext] (main) Apache Camel 3.14.1 (camel-1) started in 593ms (build:0ms init:206ms start:387ms)
2023-01-04 15:43:04,562 DEBUG [org.apa.cam.imp.DefaultCamelContext] (main) start() took 594 millis
2023-01-04 15:43:04,567 DEBUG [org.apa.cam.mai.SimpleMainShutdownStrategy] (camel-main) Await shutdown to complete
2023-01-04 15:43:04,583 INFO  [com.example.MyLogger] (main) Application is up
2023-01-04 15:43:04,583 INFO  [com.example.MyLogger] (main) Application is up
2023-01-04 15:43:04,767 INFO  [com.example.ShutdownController] (main) Setting pre shutdown sleep time to 10 seconds.
2023-01-04 15:43:04,767 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) my-app 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on JVM (powered by Quarkus 2.7.5.Final) started in 3.124s. Listening on: http://0.0.0.0:8081
2023-01-04 15:43:04,768 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Profile integration activated.
    ...(application runs normally; sends a message to in memory AMQ broker and Camel starts consuming from the queue)
```

And the 2nd test runs with these logs:

```
2023-01-04 15:43:59,606 INFO  [org.apa.cam.imp.eng.AbstractCamelContext] (main) Routes startup (total:8 started:8)
2023-01-04 15:43:59,606 INFO  [org.apa.cam.imp.eng.AbstractCamelContext] (main)     Started route1 (activemq://queue:myqueue)
2023-01-04 15:43:59,606 INFO  [org.apa.cam.imp.eng.AbstractCamelContext] (main)     Started route2 (activemq://queue:myqueue.online)
2023-01-04 15:43:59,606 INFO  [org.apa.cam.imp.eng.AbstractCamelContext] (main)     Started main (direct://main)
2023-01-04 15:43:59,606 INFO  [org.apa.cam.imp.eng.AbstractCamelContext] (main)     Started individual-endpoint (direct://individual-endpoint)
2023-01-04 15:43:59,606 INFO  [org.apa.cam.imp.eng.AbstractCamelContext] (main)     Started send-and-retry (direct://send-and-retry)
2023-01-04 15:43:59,606 INFO  [org.apa.cam.imp.eng.AbstractCamelContext] (main)     Started mapping-response (direct://mapping-response)
2023-01-04 15:43:59,606 INFO  [org.apa.cam.imp.eng.AbstractCamelContext] (main)     Started reply-queue (direct://reply-queue)
2023-01-04 15:43:59,606 INFO  [org.apa.cam.imp.eng.AbstractCamelContext] (main)     Started route3 (direct://receive.ack.response)
2023-01-04 15:43:59,606 INFO  [org.apa.cam.imp.eng.AbstractCamelContext] (main) Apache Camel 3.14.1 (camel-1) started in 452ms (build:0ms init:202ms start:250ms)
2023-01-04 15:43:59,607 DEBUG [org.apa.cam.imp.DefaultCamelContext] (main) start() took 453 millis
2023-01-04 15:43:59,631 INFO  [com.example.MyLogger] (main) Application is up
2023-01-04 15:43:59,631 INFO  [com.example.MyLogger] (main) Application is up
2023-01-04 15:43:59,617 DEBUG [org.apa.cam.mai.SimpleMainShutdownStrategy] (camel-main) Await shutdown to complete
2023-01-04 15:43:59,756 INFO  [com.example.MyLogger] (main) Application is down
2023-01-04 15:43:59,756 INFO  [com.example.MyLogger] (main) Application is down
2023-01-04 15:43:59,757 DEBUG [org.apa.cam.mai.SimpleMainShutdownStrategy] (main) Shutdown called
2023-01-04 15:43:59,757 DEBUG [org.apa.cam.mai.MainLifecycleStrategy] (main) CamelContext: camel-1 is stopping, triggering shutdown of the JVM.
```

The class `ShutdownController` listens for Quarkus shutdown event.

```java
public class ShutdownController implements ShutdownListener {
    static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ShutdownController.class);
    private final long preShutdownSleep;

    public ShutdownController() {
        this.preShutdownSleep = (Long)ConfigProvider.getConfig().getOptionalValue("com.example.shutdown-controller.pre-shutdown-sleep", Long.class).orElse(ProfileManager.getLaunchMode() == LaunchMode.TEST ? 0L : 10L);
        LOGGER.info("Setting pre shutdown sleep time to {} seconds.", this.preShutdownSleep);
    }

    public ShutdownController(final int preShutdownSleep) {
        this.preShutdownSleep = (long)preShutdownSleep;
    }

    public void preShutdown(final ShutdownNotification notification) {
        LOGGER.info("Pre shutdown received. Waiting fully functionally for {} seconds.", this.preShutdownSleep);
        this.sleep();
        LOGGER.info("Continuing shutdown");
        notification.done();
    }

    private void sleep() {
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(this.preShutdownSleep);
        } catch (InterruptedException var2) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

    }
}
```

Notice that Camel `SimpleMainShutdownStrategy` is called but in the second test, it does not wait for 10s. Why?

I see this part in `SimpleMainShutdownStrategy` class:

```java
    @Override
    public boolean isRunAllowed() {
        return !completed.get();
    }

    @Override
    public void addShutdownListener(ShutdownEventListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shutdown() {
        if (completed.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
            LOG.debug("Shutdown called");
            latch.countDown();
            for (ShutdownEventListener l : listeners) {
                try {
                    LOG.trace("ShutdownEventListener: {}", l);
                    l.onShutdown();
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    // ignore as we must continue
                    LOG.debug("Error during ShutdownEventListener: {}. This exception is ignored.", l, e);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void await() throws InterruptedException {
        LOG.debug("Await shutdown to complete");
        latch.await();
    }
```

So maybe it is because in the 1st case, `ShutdownController` has no instance so the constructor is called, and wait for 10s; but in the 2nd test, the instance is created so it does not call constructor. But why shutdown is called before the integration test runs?

In both cases, Quarkus app starts before Camel.

Both tests have similar structure:

```java
@QuarkusIntegrationTest
@QuarkusTestResource(value = WiremockResource.class, restrictToAnnotatedClass = true)
@QuarkusTestResource(value = InMemoryAMQResource.class, restrictToAnnotatedClass = true)
@TestProfile(MyIntegrationTestProfile.class)
class MyOutboundMessageFormatIT extends MyIntegrationTestSupport { // the base class have a lot of fields like connetion, session, etc., which are used in @BeforeAll and @BeforeEach, etc. 
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MyOutboundMessageFormatIT.class);

    @InjectInMemoryAMQ
    protected BrokerService brokerService;

    @InjectWiremock
    protected WireMockServer wireMockServer;

    @Override
    WireMockServer getWiremock() {
        return wireMockServer;
    }

    @Override
    BrokerService getBroker() {
        return brokerService;
    }


    @BeforeAll
    protected static void start() throws Exception {
        LOG.debug("Connecting to AMQ");
        connectToAMQ();
    }

    @AfterAll
    protected static void stop() throws Exception {
        LOG.debug("Stopping AMQ");
        session.close();
        connection.stop();
        connection.close();
    }

    @BeforeEach
    protected void stub() {
        // global stubs
        stubAllFieldsOK();
        stubOauthOK();
    }

    @AfterEach
    protected void clearWiremockRequestsJournal() throws JMSException {
        // clear reply queue for next test
        consumeOnlineReply();
        assertEmptyNonOnlineReply();
        waitTillTokenExpires();
        wireMockServer.resetRequests();
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, at the end of the log I see the cause:

```
2023-01-05 14:13:52,530 INFO  [org.apa.cam.imp.eng.AbstractCamelContext] (main) Apache Camel 3.14.1 (camel-1) shutdown in 942ms (uptime:1s341ms)
2023-01-05 14:13:52,549 ERROR [io.qua.run.Application] (main) Port 8081 seems to be in use by another process. Quarkus may already be running or the port is used by another application.
2023-01-05 14:13:52,549 WARN  [io.qua.run.Application] (main) Use 'netstat -anop | grep 8081' to identify the process occupying the port.
2023-01-05 14:13:52,549 WARN  [io.qua.run.Application] (main) You can try to kill it with 'kill -9 <pid>'.
```

So actually there cannot be 2 integration tests running; seems Quarkus application can only start once and will occupy the port.

---

At last, I solved this by allowing duplicate message in my ActiveMQ in memory broker URL, and put all cases into one test.

The original issue is that I was reusing the JSON message body between tests, and somehow ActiveMQ is ignoring the message, so no message entered the queue, so 2nd test was not running; also, changing stubbing out of Wiremock resource class seems impossible(at first I let Wiremock return 200, but in the last test I want to simulate 404 case), that's why I wanted to separate the tests.

Now, I use an id to mark the stub I want to change, and in test I call `wiremockServer.editStub()` to change the stub, also I stop tests from running in parallel with `@TestMethodOrder(value = MethodOrderer.MethodName.class)`, then things start to work. So no dividing into 2 test classes is needed now.